# R: how to change knitr output file permission

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using knitr to output a word file, but the resulting file's permission is read only. How can I change it so that the outputted file can be edited/changed by the user?

Comment: `system("attrib +r c:/path/to/file.docx")`? It much be something unique to your system, because when I knit a file to docx, it is not read-only.

Comment: It's read-only on the RStudio preview windows. But if you check the properties of the file outside it's not read-only

Comment: @Tung You are absolutely correct, and I hope you could post it as an answer, since I think some other users could be confused by this "read-only" note, too. You can actually edit this document by clicking the menu in Word (I don't use Word, so I don't remember which menu it was the last time I tried).

Comment: @YihuiXie: Thanks for the confirmation. I'll post my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's shown as read-only in the Preview. If you exit and re-open the Word file, the "read-only" tag will be gone. Checking the file properties in Windows explorer also confirms this

[image]

Comment: If you are doing a series of knitr generated documents, it is a pain to manually go to word and close them. Is there some automated way to accomplish this?